# jQuery nth child trouble

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap every set of three .item divs in a larger div, how can I do that?

Original:

```
<div class="item">..</div>
<div class="item">..</div>
<div class="item">..</div>
<div class="item">..</div>
<div class="item">..</div>
<div class="item">..</div>
```

After jQuery:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="item">..</div>
    <div class="item">..</div>
    <div class="item">..</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="item">..</div>
    <div class="item">..</div>
    <div class="item">..</div>
</div>
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the nth child equation - any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) like this:

```
var divs = $("div.item");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
  divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
}
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/jHVSR/1/)